# Simulate null distribution for multiple variables using infer package

Tags: r, simulation, distribution

Using the data frame

```
df <- data.frame(user_id = seq(50),
                 var_1 = rnorm(50),
                 var_2 = rnorm(50),
                 var_3 = rnorm(50)
)
```

I could, for example, simulate the null distribution for variable `var_1`  with the infer package

```
null_dist <- df %>%
        
        specify(response = var_1) %>% 
        
        hypothesize(null = "point", mu = 0) %>% 
        
        generate(reps = 10000, type = "bootstrap") %>% 
        
        calculate(stat = "mean")
```

and then visualize it by

```
null_dist %>% visualize()
```

How would I apply this procedure to all 3 variables at once, for example after transforming `df` to `df_2`?

```
df_2 <- df %>%
        
        pivot_longer(starts_with("var_"), "variable", values_to = "values")
```

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be:

1. Transformation of the initial  data frame

```
df_2 <- df %>%
        
        pivot_longer(starts_with("var_"), "variable", values_to = "values")
```

2. Defining a function

```
null_dist_func <- function(df){
        
        df %>% specify(response = values) %>%
                hypothesize(null = "point", mu = 0) %>%
                generate(reps = 1000, type = "bootstrap") %>%
                calculate(stat = "mean")
}
```

3. Split-apply-combine approach

```
null_dist <- df_2 %>% select(-user_id) %>%
        
        split(list(.$variable)) %>%
        
        map(null_dist_func) %>% 
        
        bind_rows(.id = "variable")
```

Visualization of a selected null distribution

```
null_dist %>% filter(variable == "var_2") %>% visualize()
```